# How to run terminal with a given profile via command line in MacOS

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm new to Mac and I need to start Terminal with a specific profile via command line.
I need it to simulate an x86 environment on an M1 machine for executing an old Java application.

It works perfectly if I open terminal and write the command interactively, but I'm looking to write a .command to perform automatically the task.

So I'm thinking about a command like this:

`open -a Terminal -n --args <use that profile> <run some command>`

Is there a way to tell Terminal which profile to use this way? or some other way to perform the task?

Thanks

Comment: Any ideas? Need some more details? I can't find answers online, thanks!